# Forecasting ARIMA with xreg

Tags: r, forecasting

I'm trying to forecast time in time out ("TiTo") for someone ordering food at a restaurant using the code below.  TiTo is the total time it takes someone from the time they walk through the door to the time they get their food.  TimeTT is the time the customer spends talking to the waiter.  I believe TimeTT is a predictor of TiTo and I would like to use it as a covariate in the forecast for TiTo.  I've read some about ARIMA, and as I understand it you add the predictors to the model in the xreg parameter.  I'm thinking of the xreg parameter as something like the independent variable for a regression model, like lm(TiTo ~ TimeTT).  Is this the correct way to think of the xreg parameter?  Also what does the error message below mean?  Do I need to convert TimeTT into a time series to use it in the xreg parameter?  I'm new to forecasting so all help is very appreciated.

Forecast Attempt:

```
OV<-zoo(SampleData$TiTo, order.by=SampleData$DateTime)

eData <- ts(OV, frequency = 24)

Train <-eData[1:15000]

Test <- eData[15001:20809]

Arima.fit <- auto.arima(Train)

Acast<-forecast(Arima.fit, h=5808, xreg = SampleData$TimeTT)
```

Error:

Error in if (ncol(xreg) != ncol(object$call$xreg)) stop("Number of regressors does not match fitted model") : 
  argument is of length zero

Data:

```
dput(Train[1:5])
c(1152L, 1680L, 1680L, 968L, 1680L)

dput(SampleData[1,]$TimeTT)
structure(1156L, .Label = c("0.000000", "0.125000", "0.142857",  
"96.750000", "97.800000", "99.000000", "99.600000", "NULL"), class = "factor")
```

Comment: Post an example of your data.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me kristang.  I've posted some sample data.  I didn't post all of the data for TimeTT, just a sample.  I can right off the bat looking at it that I was subsetting my dataframe wrong before, but should xreg be a data frame?  Does xreg need to be a timeseries of the same length as your training data?  Also do I have the conept behind auto arima with xreg correct, that is that I can forecast one timeseries ("TiTo") and add predictors to the forecast using xreg?

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the `xreg` when you estimate the model itself, and these need to be forecasted ahead as well. So this will look something like:

```
Arima.fit <- auto.arima(Train, xreg = SampleData$TimeTT)
forecast(Arima.fit, h = 508, xreg = NewData$TimeTT)
```

Here is an example using `Arima` and `xreg` from Rob Hyndman (here is the [link](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/longseasonality/) to the example, but to read more about using contemporaneous covariates in ARIMA models go [here](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/9/1)), this is analogous to `auto.arima`.

```
n <- 2000
m <- 200
y <- ts(rnorm(n) + (1:n)%%100/30, f=m)

library(forecast)
fit <- Arima(y, order=c(2,0,1), xreg=fourier(y, K=4))
plot(forecast(fit, h=2*m, xreg=fourierf(y, K=4, h=2*m)))
```

Hope this helps.